# Javascript extending Inheritance

Tags: javascript, inheritance, ecmascript-6

I have 2 files below

`transaction.js`

```
class Transaction {
  constructor (txn) {
    this.txn = txn;
  }
  startTransaction () {
    this.conn.send(this.txn);
  }
}
```

`index.js`

```
const Transaction = require('./transaction')
class Index {
  constructor(option = {}) {
    this.conn = this.setConnection(option.url); // { url: '', send: [Function] }
    this.txn = Transaction;
  }
}
let index = new Index({url: ''})
```

I need to have `index.conn` object to be assigned under `new index.transaction()`, when newly instantiated. So that, code below would work

```
let transaction = new index.txn({ data: 'here' });
transaction.startTransaction();
```

Any possible way in your mind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Function.prototype.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) to pass the connection to the transaction:

**transaction.js**

```
class Transaction {
    constructor (conn, txn) {
        this.conn = conn;
        this.txn = txn;
    }
    startTransaction () {
        this.conn.send(this.txn);
    }
}
```

**index.js**

```
class Index {
    constructor(option = {}) {
        this.conn = this.setConnection(option.url); // { url: '', send: [Function] }
        this.txn = Transaction.bind({}, this.conn); /*
                                                       .bind() here will create a new function
                                                       that ensures this.conn will be passed as the
                                                       first argument to Transaction
                                                     */
    }
}
```

**And run**

```
let index = new Index({url: ''});
let transaction = new index.txn({ data: 'here' });
transaction.startTransaction();
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need! Thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

**Transaction.js**

```
class Transaction {
  constructor (txn) {
    this.txn = txn;
  }
  startTransaction (conn) {
    conn.send(this.txn);
  }
}
```

**Index.js**

```
const Transaction = require('./transaction')
class Index {
  constructor(option = {}) {
    this.conn = this.setConnection(option.url); // { url: '', send: [Function] }
    this.txn = Transaction;
  }
  startTransaction (){
  this.txn.startTransaction(this.conn);
  }
}
let index = new Index({url: ''})
```

**Then run**

```
let index = new index.txn({ data: 'here' });
index.startTransaction();
```

Comment: thanks for the answer :D
but I feel @Hyddan answer above is more appropriate